# accessing useContext state-variable returns undefined value

Tags: reactjs, react-native, use-context

I am trying to implement authentication flow where a User can log in and log out. If the user presses a button in `LoginScreen`, the `signIn()` function from `AuthContext` is called to handle the login. When the login was successful, the `user` in `AuthContext` is being set, as seen in the first code snippet. Here is already the problem, when I `console.log` the `user` after `setUser(builtUser)`, it is undefined.

In the second code snippet, I am trying to access the `user` which i have set as explained before in the `signIn()`function. Here the same problem, it is undefined. I expected the Context to be accessible everywhere but the state somehow is not set.

I am relatively new to `react(-native)` but I think that it has something to do with the fact that states are updated asynchrounously so I can't be sure that it is set immediately.

What would be a proper way to get around this? I watched this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hln37dE19bs&t=3155s) and followed along, he is able to acces the `user`from other components.. Have I overseen something obvious?

**AuthContext.tsx**

```js
export const AuthContext = React.createContext<{
  authPending: boolean;
  user: UserData;
  getUser: () => void;
  /** signIn by using browserAuth*/
  signIn: () => void;
  signOut: () => void;
  /** signIn manually by providing steamID64 in the input form  */
  signIn64: (steamId: string) => void;
}>({
  authPending: false,
  user: null,
  getUser: () => {},
  signIn: () => {},
  signOut: () => {},
  signIn64: (steamId: string) => {},
});
export const AuthProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<UserData>(null);
  const [authPending, setAuthPending] = useState<boolean>(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getExistingUser() {
      let loggedInId = await getLoggedInUser();
      if (loggedInId) {
        let usrString = await getStorageUser(loggedInId);
        if (usrString) {
          let usr = await JSON.parse(usrString);
          console.log("User existing with ID:  " + usr?.steamId);
          return usr;
        } else {
          console.log("User not existing");
        }
      }
      return null;
    }

    getExistingUser().then((storageUser) => setUser(storageUser));
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        authPending,
        user,
        getUser: async () => {
          if (user) {
            return user;
          }
        },
        signIn: async () => {
          let result = await startAuth();
          // after startAuth, so the user sees loading screen only after the modalBrowser closes
          setAuthPending(true);
          if (result.type != "success" || !result.steamID) {
            console.log("ERROR SIGNIN");
            setAuthPending(false);
            setUser(null);
            return undefined;
          }

          console.log("signing with id: " + result.steamID);

          // FETCH USER PROFILE
          let profileResponse = await fetchUserProfile(result.steamID);

          // FETCH USER INVENTORY
          let inventoryResponse = await fetchUserInventory(result.steamID);

          // merge both responses
          let builtUser = buildUser(profileResponse, inventoryResponse);

          // if something went wrong inside buildUser function
          if (!builtUser) {
            setAuthPending(false);
            return null;
          }
          console.log("User : " + builtUser.userName);
          console.log("Items: " + builtUser.inventory?.itemsCount);

          setStorageUser(builtUser?.steamId, builtUser);
          setLoggedInUser(builtUser?.steamId);

          setUser(builtUser);
          console.log("state user: " + user?.avatarUrl);
          setAuthPending(false);
          //AsyncStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(fakeUser));
        },
         // rest of the methods...
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

**LoginScreen.tsx**

only the important parts of the code here. The `signIn` is being called but `user` is undefined

```
const { signIn, authPending, user, signIn64 } = useContext(AuthContext);

 <AnimatedTouchable
        onPress={async () => {
          console.log("starting .... ");
          await signIn();
          if (user) {
            console.log(
              "[SUCCESS] User <" +
                user.userName +
                "> Authenticated with id: <" +
                user.steamId +
                ">"
            );

            navigation.navigate("UserProfile");
          }
        }}
```

Comment: Are you wrapping your app in the context provider?

Comment: yes, and I do have acces to the context-functions.